# Change fancybox body id on load

Tags: jquery, fancybox, typoscript

I have a background image in my site, but when I open a fancybox, that
background image would appear in fancybox's body, too. Is there a way to get the body element inside the iframe so that I can apply an id to it?

I tried this:

```
$("#appointment-form").fancybox({
        'width'     : 500,
        'height'    : 300,
        'transitionIn'  : 'fade',
        'transitionOut' : 'fade',
        'type'      : 'iframe',
        'onComplete'    : function () {
                             $('body').attr('id', 'fancybox_body'); 
                          }
});
```

But it changes the id of the main page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get at the `<body>` inside the `<iframe>` a slightly different way, like this:

```
$('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('body').attr('id', 'fancybox_body');
```

You need to first get the `<iframe>` fancybox uses with an [#ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) then do a [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) on it's [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get elements inside.

Comment: Thanks, Nick! I tried and it works, but I already found a more "native" solution in typo3. Thanks again!

Comment: @cili - Welcome :)  make sure to either accept an answer or post what you did as the answer (you can accept *that* 2 days after), it'll help the next person coming along with the same issue that googles and finds your question :)

Answer (score 0):

It changes the id because of

```
$('body').attr('id', 'fancybox_body');
```

Comment: What are you talking about? I don't understand.

Comment: His question is the id changes on the main page, the reason is because of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to change the body's ID in the first place?

Better give the main `body` a `class` like, say, `page`. Apply the background image only to bodies of that class.

```
body.page
 {
  background-image: url(.....)
}
```

Comment: That is what I was trying to do. The hard part was adding an id (or class). I am working on a typo3 site and I managed this with typoscript. Thanks!